# Check if a port is open by socket in linux but connection refused

Tags: linux, sockets, python-sockets

I am using python socket package to check if a port is open on linux, the code is

```py
def is_available(p):            
   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   result = sock.connect_ex(('127.0.0.1', p))            
   sock.close()
   return result == 0
```

I passed 8980 to 8983 to this method, all results are 111, which means not available, which I suppose is connection refused?

But I use `netstat -tnlp` in terminal but these ports are not used.

Why?..

Comment: If nothing is listening on those ports, then you would expect a "connection refused" message. It sounds like your code is behaving exactly as expected.

Comment: @larsks Seems I mixed the concept of "open" and "available".. so stupid of me..